# Filling a Combobox with Value and Display members. Custom Class vs Basic SQL String

Tags: sql, vb.net, dictionary, combobox

I want to fill a ComboBox with just 3 items with display and value members.
These items will never change and so will hard coded.

Which would be a better method to fill this combo box:

1. Make a custom dictionary and create 3 items to add to the combo box.

   ```vb
   Dim comboSource As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
   comboSource.Add("1", "SpareElement1")
   comboSource.Add("2", "SpareElement2")
   comboSource.Add("3", "SpareElement3")
   ComboBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(comboSource, Nothing)
   ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value"
   ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Key"
   ```
2. Pass a SQL query to force a dataset return that I want:

   ```vb
   ComboBox1.ValueMember = "id"
   ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
   ComboBox.Datasource = RUNSQL("SELECT 'SpareElement1' as Name, 1 as ID UNION SELECT 'SpareElement2' as Name, 2 as ID UNION SELECT 'SpareElement3' as Name, 3 as ID")
   ```

The custom dictionary wouldn't get used anywhere else and neither the dataset apart from being bound.
What are the pro's and cons of doing either way?

Comment: This is very subjective, there is no good way without know the full content of the application. But what ever you do, I would have a class or method GetSpareElement() that would return the list. Then, if you change from hardcoded to database, you only need to change it at one place. The DisplayMemeber, ValueMember would stay the same.

Comment: Hi the_lotus. The program is for running a series of tests on data we hold for different clients. In one particular table we have 3 spare fields that can hold additional data depending on the client. The drop down will allow a person to select one of those particular fields for testing depending on what we have stored in there. A "Include this" option if you will, the test in question will look at the standard fields for that data type and one of these extra additional fields, if needed.